# How to filter a TreeGrid?

Tags: filter, smartgwt, treegrid

I currently have a `TreeGrid` which shows nodes with **names**. The data is coming from a manually populated `DataSource`.

When setting the filter on the `nodeName` field, The filter is not done recursevily and thus I can only filter the **Root node**.

How can I tell the filter to search for matches in child nodes?

**PS:** in the code below, I have 3 nodes `Root` > `Run` > `Child1`. If i try the filter and type "**R**", I get `Root` and `Run`. But if i Type "**C**", I get "**no results found**"

### Code

### DataSource:

```
package murex.otk.gwt.gui.client.ui.datasource;

import java.util.List;

import murex.otk.gwt.gui.client.ui.record.TreeRecord;

import com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource;
import com.smartgwt.client.data.fields.DataSourceIntegerField;
import com.smartgwt.client.data.fields.DataSourceTextField;

public class ClassesDataSource extends DataSource {

    private static ClassesDataSource instance = null;

    public static ClassesDataSource getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ClassesDataSource("classesDataSource");
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ClassesDataSource(String id) {
        setID(id);

        DataSourceTextField nodeNameField = new DataSourceTextField("nodeName");
        nodeNameField.setCanFilter(true);
        nodeNameField.setRequired(true);

        DataSourceIntegerField nodeIdField = new DataSourceIntegerField("nodeId");
        nodeIdField.setPrimaryKey(true);
        nodeIdField.setRequired(true);

        DataSourceIntegerField nodeParentField = new DataSourceIntegerField("nodeParent");
        nodeParentField.setRequired(true);
        nodeParentField.setForeignKey(id + ".nodeId");
        nodeParentField.setRootValue(0);

        setFields(nodeIdField, nodeNameField, nodeParentField);
        setClientOnly(true);
    }

    public void populateDataSource(List<String> classNames) {
        TreeRecord root = new TreeRecord("Root", 0);
        addData(root);
        TreeRecord child1 = new TreeRecord("Child1", root.getNodeId());
        addData(child1);
        TreeRecord child2 = new TreeRecord("Run", child1.getNodeId());
        addData(child2);
    }

}
```

### Main

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ClassesDataSource.getInstance().populateDataSource(new ArrayList<String>());
    final TreeGrid employeeTree = new TreeGrid();
    employeeTree.setHeight(350);
    employeeTree.setDataSource(ClassesDataSource.getInstance());
    employeeTree.setAutoFetchData(true);
    TreeGridField field = new TreeGridField("nodeName");
    field.setCanFilter(true);
    employeeTree.setFields(field);
    employeeTree.setShowFilterEditor(true);     
    employeeTree.setAutoFetchAsFilter(true);
    employeeTree.setFilterOnKeypress(true);
    employeeTree.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this.

The problem was that the filter was calling the server to fetch data whereas my datasource was set to **Client Only**. To fix this, the `employeeTree` must have `employeeTree.setLoadDataOnDemand(false);`

Answer (score 0):

You may also use employeeTree.setKeepParentsOnFilter(true)

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/tree/TreeGrid.html#setKeepParentsOnFilter(java.lang.Boolean)

Comment: I tried this but apparently there is a bug in it. The search wasn't returning the correct results when a substring was provided